# Unable to type into React input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am unable to type any input into my input field. I am using React, and have already set a handleChange and a handleSubmit function. The first two input fields, for 'name' and 'email', take input just fine. But for 'favoriteCity', it doesn't seem to work.

I am wondering if it is due to a MongoDB error that I am getting.

```js
class UserPage extends Component {
    state = {
        user: [],
        newUser: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            favoriteCity: ''
        }
    }

    getAllUsers = () => {
        axios.get('/api/users')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ user: res.data })
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getAllUsers()
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const newUser = { ...this.state.newUser };
        newUser[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ newUser: newUser});
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        axios.post('/api/users', this.state.newUser)
        .then(res => {
            this.props.history.push(`/users/${res.data._id}`)
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            { /* This shows a list of All Users */ }
        {this.state.user.map(user => (
          <div key={user._id}>
          <Link to={`/users/${user._id}`}>{user.name}</Link>
          </div>
        ))}

        <h1>New User Page</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name?"
            value={this.state.newUser.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <label>Email: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email?"
            value={this.state.newUser.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <label>Favorite City: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="city"
            placeholder="Favorite City?"
            value={this.state.newUser.favoriteCity}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <Button
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
            Create User
          </Button>
        </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserPage;
```

Please help.

Comment: either change the input name to be `favoriteCity` or change the input value to be `this.state.newUser.city`

Comment: You have set `Value=` in your input fields, so you won't be able to edit them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird that email works fine, from what you posted your handleChange function is only updating the name on the newUser.

What you should see is what you type in all the inputs appear in the name input.

To fix this, you should probably have separate change handlers for each input:

- handleNameChange
- handleEmailChange
- ...

You should also consider storing name, email etc.. at the root of your state instead of nesting them in an object, that'll simplify the handler functions code.